# Handlebars loop calling @key as part of object chain

Tags: handlebars.js

I am looping through an object with Handlebars that shares the same key with another object that has data I need access to. I've been unable to render the @key as part of the object chain.

```
{{#each objectOne}}
    {{../objectTwo.[@key].title
{{/each}}
```

Is there a way to use the @key value inside of a loop to reference a different object?

---

SOLVED

Per user 76484's comments I needed a double lookup.

```
{{#each objectOne}}
    {{lookup (lookup ../objectTwo @key) 'title'}}
{{/each}}
```

Comment: You would use the lookup helper. Here is an example: https://jsfiddle.net/76484/2q0krtdp/. And the docs: https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/builtin-helpers.html#lookup

Comment: Note: For your example you would need to do two lookups: one to get the Object at property `@key` of `../objectTwo` and the second to get the `title` property of the first lookup. See: https://jsfiddle.net/76484/2q0krtdp/3/

Comment: @76484 awesome! Your second fiddle answered the problem flawlessly. Thank you so much!